# Redirect Output of Pocketsphinx_continuous to a file

Tags: output, speech-recognition

I have an ugly command:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -samprate 48000 -nfft 2048 -hmm /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us -lm 9745.lm -dict 9745.dic -inmic yes
```

*Breakdown:* It listens for any noise and when it detects some, it listens to it, and then performs speech recognition on it.

Now, the command output has a bunch of junk in it, and one line that matters. Here is the output of one speech recognition:

```
READY....
Listening...
INFO: cmn_prior.c(131): cmn_prior_update: from < 21.18 -11.87  6.18  0.77  4.42 -0.76  1.99  8.43  2.83 -1.46  3.80  6.19  3.71 >
INFO: cmn_prior.c(149): cmn_prior_update: to   < 23.28 -5.11  8.81 -0.28  0.06 -0.83  0.94  6.68  0.42  1.07  4.00  7.34  4.32 >
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1553):      814 words recognized (9/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1555):    60871 senones evaluated (684/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1559):    37179 channels searched (417/fr), 6846 1st, 21428 last
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1562):     1415 words for which last channels evaluated (15/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1564):     2626 candidate words for entering last phone (29/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1567): fwdtree 0.66 CPU 0.742 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdtree.c(1570): fwdtree 3.36 wall 3.780 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(302): Utterance vocabulary contains 21 words
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(948):      655 words recognized (7/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(950):    40095 senones evaluated (451/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(952):    31447 channels searched (353/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(954):     1794 words searched (20/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(957):     1006 word transitions (11/fr)
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(960): fwdflat 0.29 CPU 0.326 xRT
INFO: ngram_search_fwdflat.c(963): fwdflat 0.30 wall 0.333 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(1253): lattice start node <s>.0 end node </s>.70
INFO: ngram_search.c(1279): Eliminated 1 nodes before end node
INFO: ngram_search.c(1384): Lattice has 127 nodes, 473 links
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1380): Bestpath score: -2298
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1384): Normalizer P(O) = alpha(</s>:70:87) = -132973
INFO: ps_lattice.c(1441): Joint P(O,S) = -156371 P(S|O) = -23398
INFO: ngram_search.c(875): bestpath 0.01 CPU 0.011 xRT
INFO: ngram_search.c(878): bestpath 0.00 wall 0.005 xRT
HELLO
```

That `HELLO` is the only thing that matters, and I want that to be output into a file somehow.

I have already tried adding `>foo.txt` to the end of the command, which works, except it outputs everything except for `HELLO` to the file and `HELLO` never even makes it to the command line.

I've tried adding `&> foo.txt` `2> foo.txt` `>> foo.txt` and all of them cause the output to go where it says except every time it also causes `READY....`,`Listening...`, and `HELLO` to disappear.

How can I direct `HELLO` to a file, in any way, I don't care if other stuff comes with it, I can cut the other stuff out.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but it's a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31494824

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -samprate 48000 -nfft 2048 -hmm \
/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us -lm 9745.lm -dict 9745.dic \
-inmic yes 2>&1 | tee ./full-output.log | grep -v --line-buffered '^INFO:'
```

This will log **everything** to `./full-output.log`, but hide any output from the console that begins with `INFO:`. `2>&1` redirects Standard Error to Standard Output so that all output is forced through the series of pipes, rather than just Standard Output.

If you wanted to hide other lines that do not contain `INFO:`, you could use `|` in extended-`grep` syntax:

```
egrep -v --line-buffered '^INFO:|^ERROR:'
```

The `--line-buffered` option will prevent `grep` from waiting until the output from `pocketsphinx_continuous` is completely finished.

**Edit**

It's also possible that `pocketsphinx_continuous` is already putting everything you want on Standard Output and everything you don't want on Standard Error. So, you might try just doing:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -samprate 48000 -nfft 2048 -hmm \
/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us -lm 9745.lm -dict 9745.dic \
-inmic yes 2>./unwanted-stuff.log | tee ./words.log
```

This would log everything coming out on Standard Error to `./unwanted-stuff.log` and everything on Standard Output to `./words.log`.

Comment: I'll try this in the morning, thanks for the answer!

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: No dice, still just everything in the command line except for `READY` `Listening....` and `HELLO` nothing showed up in `./full-output.log`

Comment: Ok, I think I know what's going on! See my edit to the original command at the top of the post, as well as the alternate solution in my edit at the bottom. This is due to some output being on Standard Output and some being on Standard Error. This  has the potential to actually make things easier, if everything we don't want is on Standard Error :)

Comment: Everything except `HELLO` is in `unwanted-stuff.log` but `words.log` is empty. I made sure the command is working by running it without the extra stuff, and the command is working fine.

Comment: `full-output.log` contains everything but `HELLO`. I really appreciate all of your help though.

Comment: It seems that when anything is added to the end of the command `HELLO` stops being output altogether.

Comment: I've found that pocketsphinx ignores stdout as of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601701/does-pocketsphinx-ignore-stdout Would there be a way to make it not ignore stdout?

Comment: Ah, wow, it does indeed! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491536/pocketsphinx-capturing-real-time-output-of-inmic-yes-to-txt has a bit more info as well.

You can TRY `-logfn - ` or `-logfn /dev/stdout`, but you might have to patch the code as suggested in the post I just linked. But, still, my first approach at the top should work, as `2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout`.

Comment: `-logfn` redirects everything except `HELLO` which might work for me, and your first approach just outputs everything except `HELLO` to the file, and for some reason causes the `HELLO` to stop showing up in the console.

Comment: The problem was that pocketsphinx did not flush new results, you can update to latest version to fix it. I still recommend to use bindings instead of spawn the process.

Answer (score 0):

Nice and clear output:

```
 pocketsphinx_continuous  -samprate 48000 -nfft 2048 -inmic yes 2>/dev/null
```

Python module may be a better interface for these class-full objects.